# I made a jar file and when my friend tries to open it they get the error "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again"

Tags: java, windows, java-8

I made an executable jar file that works perfectly for me, but when I send it to my friend, they get the error `A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`. When they run it in the console, the extended error message is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/pathto/project
  has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), 
  this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is caused when the jar file was compiled in a newer version of java than the person who is running the jar has (E.g. you compiled the jar in Java 11 but your friend only has Java 8 installed.) This can be fixed by having your friend update Java by going to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-windows, and downloading `x64 Installer`. Then, have your friend install java by running the downloaded exe. Next go to where the exe installed the JDK, default is `C:\Program Files\Java`, and copy the filepath to the newly downloaded JDK (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1`). Finally, go to `edit the system environtment variables` in control panel, go to `Environment Variables...` Click on `Path` under `System Variables`, click the Edit button, Click the New Button, paste in the filepath you copied, click OK, then move the newly created variable to the top.